# Animação em Container

Tags: flutter

Preciso criar uma animação que ao passar o ponteiro do mouse em uma determinada área o Container expanda e ao sair dessa área o container diminua. Já sei como fazer isso ao clicar nessa área, porém preciso que isso ocorra quando eu passar com o ponteiro do mouse. Sei que o Flutter possui um Widget chamado MouseRegion, que executa uma determinada ação ao passar com o ponteiro do Mouse em uma determinada área, porém não estou conseguindo. Por gentileza, alguém pode me ajudar? Segue o código funcional abaixo.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: VariableSizeContainerExample(),
    )
  );
}

class VariableSizeContainerExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const VariableSizeContainerExample({super.key});

  @override
  _VariableSizeContainerExampleState createState() => _VariableSizeContainerExampleState();
}

class _VariableSizeContainerExampleState extends State<VariableSizeContainerExample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
    );
  }

  _toggleContainer() {
    if (_animation.status != AnimationStatus.completed) {
      setState(() {
        _controller.forward();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _controller.animateBack(0, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              MouseRegion(
                onHover: _toggleContainer(),
                child: const Text("Toggle container visibility")
              ),
              SizeTransition(
                sizeFactor: _animation,
                axis: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: const Text(
                    "This can have variable size",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Text("This is below the above container"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como só há uma animação, você pode usar `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`. Tive que colocar `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` no `Column`, pois quando o container expandia, esse Widget ia pro centro...

No `MouseRegion` você teria de usar `onEnter` e `onExit`. O `onHover` vai disparar várias vezes enquanto o mouse estiver se movendo (dentro da região).

```
MouseRegion(
  onEnter: (_) => _toggleContainer(),
  onExit: (_) => _toggleContainer(),
  child: const Text("Toggle container visibility")
)
```

A função que vai chamar os métodos da animação:

```
_toggleContainer() {
  if (_animation.status == AnimationStatus.completed || _animation.status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
    return _controller.animateBack(0, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
    
  _controller.forward();
}
```

É desnecessário chamar os métodos de animação pelo `setState`. Outro ponto importante é fazer o override do método dispose pra destruir o `_controller` quando não for mais utilizado.

Comment: Corn* dá downvote e não diz o porquê...